# Remove left spacing in <Form> component in native base

Tags: react-native, native-base

I would like to ask, how can I remove the left spacing in the Form component, I'm using native base UI for my design. Here's my code below:

```
<Form>
  <Item style={styles.loginInputItem}>
    <Input placeholder="Email address" style={styles.loginInput} placeholderTextColor="#FFFFFF" />
  </Item>
  <Item style={styles.loginInputItem}>
    <Input placeholder="Password" secureTextEntry={true} style={styles.loginInput} placeholderTextColor="#FFFFFF" />
  </Item>
  <Button block style={styles.loginButton}>
    <Text>Login</Text>
  </Button>
  <Button block style={styles.loginFacebookButton}>
    <Text>Connect with Facebook</Text>
  </Button>
  <Button block style={styles.loginGoogleButton}>
    <Text style={styles.loginGoogleButtonText}>Connect with Google</Text>
  </Button>
  <Button block transparent light>
    <Text>Forgot Password?</Text>
  </Button>
</Form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just override the style of `<Item/>` and set `marginLeft:0`

```
<Item style={{ marginLeft: 0 }}/>
```